# how can i print the content of the register ds in binary/decimal ..?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I need some help to show the content of the register DS in both binary and decimal and all i have done is converting hex to binary . How can i show what i need ?

```
.MODEL SMALL
 .STACK 100H

  .DATA
   PROMPT_1  DB  0DH,0AH,'Enter the character : $'
   PROMPT_2  DB  0DH,0AH,'The ASCII code of the given number in HEX       form     is : $'
   PROMPT_3  DB  0DH,0AH,'The ASCII code of the given number in BIN       form     is : $'
   MY_CHAR   DB  ?          
   BINARY    DB  9 DUP('$') 

 .CODE
  MAIN PROC

 MOV AX, @DATA                ; initialize DS  
 MOV DS, AX

 START:                      ; jump label 
  ; LEA DX, PROMPT_1           ; load and display the string PROMPT_1
   ;MOV AH, 9
   ;INT 21H

   MOV AH, 1                  ; read a character
   INT 21H                                      

   MOV MY_CHAR, AL ; ?¦ save char to use in binary conversion.
   MOV BL, AL                 ; move AL to BL

   CMP BL, 0DH                ; compare BL with CR
   JE END                    ; jump to label @END if BL=CR

   LEA DX, PROMPT_2           ; load and display the string PROMPT_2
   MOV AH, 9
   INT 21H

   XOR DX, DX                 ; clear DX
   MOV CX, 4                  ; move 4 to CX

   LOOP_1:                   ; loop label
     SHL BL, 1                ; shift BL towards left by 1 position
     RCL DL, 1                ; rotate DL towards left by 1 position
                              ; through carry
   LOOP LOOP_1               ; jump to label @LOOP_1 if CX!=0

   MOV CX, 4                  ; move 4 to CX

   LOOP_2:                   ; loop label
     SHL BL, 1                ; shift BL towards left by 1 position
     RCL DH, 1                ; rotate DH towards left by 1 position
                              ; through carry
   LOOP LOOP_2               ; jump to label @LOOP_2 if CX!=0

   MOV BX, DX                 ; move DX to BX
   MOV CX, 2                  ; initialize loop counter

   LOOP_3:                   ; loop label
     CMP CX, 1                ; compare CX wiht 1
     JE SECOND_DIGIT         ; jump to label @SECOND_DIGIT if CX=1
     MOV DL, BL               ; move BL to DL
     JMP NEXT                ; jump to label @NEXT

     SECOND_DIGIT:           ; jump label
       MOV DL, BH             ; move BH to DL

     NEXT:                   ; jump label

     MOV AH, 2                ; set output function

     CMP DL, 9                ; compare DL with 9
     JBE NUMERIC_DIGIT       ; jump to label @NUMERIC_DIGIT if DL<=9
     SUB DL, 9                ; convert it to number i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6
     OR DL, 40H               ; convert number to letter i.e. A,B...F
     JMP DISPLAY             ; jump to label @DISPLAY

     NUMERIC_DIGIT:          ; jump label
       OR DL, 30H             ; convert decimal to ascii code

     DISPLAY:                ; jump label
       INT 21H                ; print the character
   LOOP LOOP_3               ; jump to label @LOOP_3 if CX!=0


;? FROM CHAR TO BINARY ?
     LEA SI, BINARY+7 ; ?¦ point to string in data segment.
     MOV CX, 8        ; ?¦ maximum number of binary digits.
   BIN_CONVERSION:
     SHR MY_CHAR,1    ; ?¦ get rightmost bit.
     JC  BIT1
     MOV [BYTE PTR SI], '0'
     JMP BIN_SKIP
   BIT1:
     MOV [BYTE PTR SI], '1'
   BIN_SKIP:
     DEC SI
     LOOP BIN_CONVERSION

     LEA DX, PROMPT_3 ; ?¦ display message.
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H         
     LEA DX, BINARY   ; ?¦ display binary.
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H         

   JMP START                 ; jump to label @START

 END:                        ; jump label

 MOV AH, 4CH                  ; return control to DOS
 INT 21H
 MAIN ENDP
 END MAIN
```

Comment: https://justpaste.it/6ab67 code right here but didnt let me to place it from start

Comment: Copy ds to ax and print ax.

Comment: can you give me an example e.g. 1 code line?

Comment: because if i do that it shows me a message error

Comment: Sure, `mov ax, ds`.  Then see [Displaying numbers with DOS](//stackoverflow.com/q/45904075), or [Assembly 8086 | Sum of an array, printing multi-digit numbers](//stackoverflow.com/a/40505938), or even [How to convert a number to hex?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) or

Comment: and how can i possibly show the content of an given address (e.g. 010 hex) ?

Comment: i have tried  mov ax,10h
    mov bx,[ax]
    lea dh,bx
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

Comment: Peter, how can i possibly implement that code line in my program .. ? i'm quite new in terms of assembler

Comment: so it seems i'm on my own..

Comment: If you want people to see your replies, make sure you use @username to notify them.  You get notified because I'm commenting under your post, but I only saw your comment because the question popped up again in the recent list because of an answer being posted.

Answer (score 2):

> I need some help to show the content of the register DS in both binary and decimal

Simply move `DS` to `AX` and use the conversion routine that I show below.

```
mov ax, ds
```

> and how can i possibly show the content of an given address (e.g. 010 hex) ?

If that memory contains a byte (8 bits) write:

```
mov al, [0010h]
mov ah, 0
```

If that memory contains a word (16 bits) write:

```
mov ax, [0010h]
```

Then convert using next routine to convert to decimal representation:

```
  mov     bx, 10
  xor     cx, cx     ;Counts the number of digits
again:
  xor     dx, dx
  div     bx
  push    dx
  inc     cx
  test    ax, ax
  jnz     again
more:
  pop     dx
  add     dl, 48    ;Convert to character
  mov     ah, 02h
  int     21h
  loop    more
```

For a detailed explanation of how this works see [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075)